# How can I reset my game progress?

Tags: a-dark-room

I made a lot of progress in A Dark Room a long time ago. Now I want to start from scratch. Can I reset my progress somehow?

Comment: There's a restart link at the bottom right of the screen. I haven't tried it because I don't want to lose my progress, but wouldn't that do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

As Lex said in his comment there is a restart button. Once you hit it, a dialog box will pop up and check to make sure you really want to restart the game. Hit yes and you will start again in the dark room where you have to light the fire. You won't be able to get back your data unless it is on a save slot so be careful.